# Auto-Size UITableViewCell's internal UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, autosize

I'll be glad if someone will help me solve the following issue for me.

I'm trying to build UITableViewController with different dynamic cells.
Any cell has different height so I did override heightForRow from UITableViewDelegate and returned UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

By then, for every cell I have been added to my UITableView, all gone fine until I tried to add the following attached one:
[Cell example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd7BQ.png).

On runtime, heightForRow for the cell below was called, the height of the internal UITableView was 0 because UITableViewAutomaticDimension didn't consider it's height.

My question is how heightForRow from outside can consider an internal UITableView with different dynamic row heights?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your question is not clear ! what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **UITableViewDelegate** methods for height support

```
// Variable height support

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You can calculate the inner table height and return it here:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       // check if table view is the outertable view in case you have the same delegate
       // let customCellHeight = number of subCells * heightOfSubCell + padding;
    return customCellHeight;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my cells are dynamic and have different heights. I can't use your answer. Is there any other solution you can suggest?